# How to implement Action delegate?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class

```
    public class TextBoxConfig
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and one other utility class that has a Method that accepts TextBoxConfig as a parameter like this

```
    public class Util
    {
      public static TextBox ApplySettings(TextBoxConfig  config)
      {
         //Doing something
      }
    }
```

In general I can call Util class ApplySettings method like this

```
    TextBoxConfig config  = new TextBoxConfig();
    config.Caption = "Name";
    config.FieldName = "UserName"
    config.Width = 20;
    config.Name = "txtName";

    TextBox txt = Util.ApplySettings(config);
```

but I want to pass parameter to ApplySettings like this

```
    TextBox txt = Util.ApplySettings(o =>
    {
        o.Caption = "Name";
        o.FieldName = "UserName"
        o.Width = 20;
        o.Name = "txtName";
    });
```

Please suggest me how can I do it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, brace yourself: here is the same thing, just enforced with lambda expressions.

```
TextBox txt = Util.ApplySettings(o =>
{
    o.Caption = "Name";
    o.FieldName = "UserName";
    o.Width = 20;
    o.Name = "txtName";
});

public class Util
{
    public static TextBox ApplySettings(TextBoxConfig config)
    {
        //Doing something
    }

    public static TextBox ApplySettings(Action<TextBoxConfig> modifier)
    {
        var config = new TextBoxConfig();
        modifier(config);

        return ApplySettings(config);            
    }
}
```

I had to add some semicolons after the statements. And I'd prefer the other answer. But I hope this fulfills your desire for lambda expressions.

Comment: +1: For answering the question (regardless of how absurd it might sound ;p)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same as your wish, but pretty close:

```
TextBox txt = Util.ApplySettings(new TextBoxConfig()
{
    Caption = "Name",
    FieldName = "UserName",
    Width = 20,
    Name = "txtName"
});
```

Note the commas after each setting. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for you comment this is same as I am creating instance, but I want to use Lambda expression.

Comment: @Neeraj Gupta, what for? Lambda is a function, but you are not passing a function.

Comment: to set TextBoxConfig class properties as I asked to set

Comment: Why do you want to use >lamda expressions< instead of doing it nice and clean?

Comment: @Neeraj Gupta, what exactly do you want to achieve by using a lambda? Why do you think this solution is not good enough?

Comment: I want to know how I can implement my asked scenario using Lambda